# Recurring Google Apps Script Web App Error

Tags: google-apps-script

Hope you are well.

I've created two Google Apps Script projects.

A primary script and a library used by the primary. It makes use of a trigger.

I've embedded this script into a Google Site and authorized it.

For reasons, I am unable to comprehend, the following error is emailed to the account that embedded the script into its Google Site.

"We're sorry, we were unable to fetch authorization credentials. Please wait a bit and try again."

The error emails are coming in sporadically. No fixed amount of time between each.

Difficult to diagnose. Yes, I have removed and readded it.

Comment: I too get this notification sometimes. I just ignore it because it is temporary.

Comment: Definitely not temporary. I've been getting it for days now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like I've stopped the errors from occurring by doing the following.

1. Revoked all script permissions

   ```
   Google Account > Security > Manage access > Revoke Access
   ```
2. Made a copy of my Google Apps Web App Script

   ```
   Apps Script Editor > File > Make a Copy
   ```
3. Deleted the original script file from my Drive folder and trash
4. Deleted the Google Site the Apps Script Gadget was embedded in. Just removing the Apps Script Gadget did not help.

   ```
   Google Sites > More > Manage Site > General > Delete this Site
   ```
5. Removed the site from Google Sites Deleted items

   ```
   Google Sites > More > Manage Site > General > Deleted items > Delete Permanently
   ```
6. Removed all triggers from Script App

   ```
   Apps Script Editor > Resources > All your triggers
   ```
7. Renamed function called by trigger