# Problems retrieving formResponse title

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on Google Apps Script which should process data submitted from the Google Form.

Problem is that I'm getting this error after execution of `itemResponse.getItem().getTitle()`:

```
Execution failed: Failed to retrieve form data. Please wait and try again. (line 20, file "Code") [0.664 seconds total runtime]
```

Example:

I created a sample form with sample questions (question1, question2 ... question10).

In Script editor i created a simple script to log the question titles:

```
function checkSubmitted() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = formResponses[i];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    Logger.log(itemResponses.length);
    for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j ++) {
      var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
      var item = itemResponse.getItem();
      Logger.log(item.getTitle());              //this is the problematic line
      Logger.log(item.getId());
    }
  }
}
```

Sometimes it gets logged just 9 question sometimes about 16 question, looks to me like it is random, because in some forms with fewer question this code get through some formResponses and than it die on third question.

Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem with a script that was working fine just yesterday. Honestly, I think there's a problem with the platform. Googling it return no results but this very post. The closer I've seen is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170538/recurring-google-apps-script-web-app-error), and the answers did not help.

Comment: Okay, today it's working correctly so it looks like there was probably  problem on the side of Drive yesterday.

Comment: @Beneato So please accept this answer, so everybody will see it's solved ;)